# Confusing method return type, need some clarification

Tags: java, methods

Our teacher told us to expand and finish a class template he made. I am pretty familiar with return types, but this one really confuses me.

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int methodName
```

Could anyone enlighten me or point me to a proper place to read? I found it a bit icky to google this specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for [**Generics in java**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Coming to your return type its an **int**.

`<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`  is not an return type of your method, 
you are declaring a generic type `T` which you can use inside your method body.and your generic type states that the type T should be an Object which implements Comparable interface.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int methodName
 ^                 ^                              ^
Access spec        Generic Type decl               return type
```